# Firebase's KeepSynced and persistenceEnabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase's `KeepSynced` and `persistenceEnabled` but i don't understand it completely.

I have 2 questions -

1. What do this functions do exactly?  I understand that they connected to cache and offline logic but why do i need them both?
2. I have a list of categories, and after the user choose a category i show a list of all groups related to this category. 
   I'm using firebase database.
   How can i create cache for the groups, but at the same time refresh the group list after the user choose category? Is it possible to only refresh the data that is missing from the cache?

thanks for the help.